# Convert each value in an object to a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, object

I have an object with both numbers and strings as values, like this:

```
nums = {"one": 1, "two":2, "three":"3"}
```

And I need to convert each of those values into strings, like so:

```
nums = {"one": "1", "two":"2", "three":"3"}
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Is it something like:

```
$.each(nums, function(key,val){
    key.val = val.toString;
});
```

or something??  There are no nested objects, so it's just key:value, none of the values are objects with their own values, in other words.  So a loop would work and I don't have to worry about breaking some kind of nested object as one of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, except you need to access the properties of the object using bracket notation, and `toString` is a method, so needs trailing `()`. Try this:

```
$.each(nums, function(key, val){
    nums[key] = val.toString();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want output like this:

```js
var nums = {"one": 1, "two":2, "three":"3"};

$.each(nums, function(key,val){
    val = ""+val;
  nums[key] = val;
});

console.log(nums);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, because in Javascript, an integer plus a blank string equals a string!  Thanks!